# Does HTML5 socket's database save data?

Tags: database

Does an HTML5 socket save data into the database or is the passage like a "pass and not save data"?

So is it like this:

```
      Client1Send -> Server -> Client2Read -> Server doesn't store data
```

or this?

```
      Client1Send -> Server -> Client2Read -> Server stores data
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about HTML5 **WebSockets**, NO.

The WebSocket server doesn't store data unless you explicitly write code to do so.